# Numbers got unrounded after applying pandas styles

Tags: pandas, pandas-styles

I rounded numbers before applying pandas styles, it worked fine. However, after applying styles, the numbers got unrounded. I don't get it.

example data

```
d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c']*2, 'col2': [1.111, 1.112, 1.113] * 2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col2'] = round(df['col2'], 2)
```

```
    col1 col2
0   a   1.11
1   b   1.11
2   c   1.11
3   a   1.11
4   b   1.11
5   c   1.11
```

applying styles to the whole row by specifying the index

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: pink' 
                                  if (x.name == 3 )
                                  else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```

[image]

The ideal output should be showing rounded numbers and highlight index 3

Thank you

Comment: If I round the numbers after applying the function, the highlight is gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The styler differentiates the "*display* value from the *actual* value".

If you'd like to override the *display* behaviour you must specify a [format style](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values):

```
(
    df.style.format({'col2': "{:.2f}"})
        .apply(lambda _: np.where(df.index == 3, 'background: pink', ''))
)
```

[image: styled table]